# Sub Menu not displaying in NavBar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6k1o0w2/4/) with a responsive  (well, sort of) layout.

However, I am struggling to find a way of adding a 'subsection' to it (making it similar/a accordion nav menu.

I haven't the best/(any for that matter) css knowledge, and so any help is much appreciated!

Snippet of the css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 860px){ 
  .text{
    display:none;
  }

  .nav-container , a{
    width: 70px;

  }

  a:hover{
    width:200px; 
    z-index:1;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px black;
  }

  a:hover  .text {
    display:block;
    padding-left:30%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px){
  .nav-container, a{ width:50px;}
  span[class ^= "icon"]{ left:8px;}
}
```

I am trying to create it so as to have a 'submenu' like:

```
+----------------+-----+
|                |     |
||Menu1          |     |
| |sub menuA     | ||| |
||Menu2          |     |
| |sub menuB     |     |
|                |     |
+----------------+-----+
                    ^
                    |
              DevExpress content splitter
```

How should I be structuring my `subChild` class in order to achieve this?

my function so far is:

```
$('li').click(function () {

    $(this).addClass('active')
         .siblings()
         .removeClass('active');
});
```

Any advice/help is much appreciated.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/404pwuqq/) which is how my project is currently displaying (or 'not' for that matter :L)  - You will have to excuse the inline styling, it was mainly from so much testing/etc

Comment: @Paulie_D sorry, was old fiddle in tabs. Updated now

Comment: If you remove the height from the `li` the submenu is already there. All you have to do then is hide it by default and get it to show on click of the parent.

Comment: You make it sound so easy! web dev is *nothing* like winforms/anything 'relate-able'

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

I was able to obtain my answer from @Paulie_D's suggestion of looking at the height within the `a` and `li` blocks.

[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/404pwuqq/2/) shows it in action!

Removing Height Attribute as shown below gives:

```
li{
  /*height:50px; */
  position:relative;
  background: linear-gradient(#292929, #242424);
}

a {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  /*height:100%;*/
  width:100%;
  line-height:50px;
  color:#bbb;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left:25%;
  border-left:5px solid transparent;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```